# Should I Use Microsoft Outlook 2007 Or Windows Live Mail?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007, windows-live-mail, import-mail

I want to import Thunderbird email into Outlook 2007 but this can only be done through Outlook Express or Windows Live Mail.

**Question:**

Since Microsoft Outlook 2007 is not free and Windows Live Mail is free, using Outlook 2007 when importing email next time on another computer might be a hassle. I have Office 2007 OEM on both of laptops, but what if i decide to import email on **different laptop/desktop** that won't have OEM Office 2007?

While it seems as Windows Live Mail is more logical way to go, i still think that it is sad not to use Office 2007 since it was already installed on my system and Windows Live Mail will require installing. I just don't like installing another application with same purpose.

Comment: Are you asking for how to import your mails or for which one **you** should use?

Comment: Considering his past posts. "Probably which one **you** should use..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have neither the desire nor the need for a calendar, task list, Contacts manager or Exchange, there is no need to use Outlook.

If all you do is email, Live Mail makes more sense.

Both products have very good portability.  There isn't a single legitimate mail service that **can't import Outlook formats**.  It is because Outlook is one of the most widely used PIMs out there.

Comment: When it comes to portability across platforms, I think Thunderbird is definitely the clear winner there.

Comment: Too bad that wasn't the question huh?

Comment: I still think your answer was a good one.

Comment: It was an easy question.  _shrug_